# How are erb layouts implemented?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates

How are Rails ERB's layouts implemented? I tried looking through the source, but I couldn't determine where/how they work.

I am specifically interested in how the **yield** part works, how erb includes the rendered view in a template.

The reason I need it, is so that I can use it for code generation, non Rails, non HTML related ( and because it would be interesting to know how they work )

Comment: Have you read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html ?

Comment: Yes. Was there something I should have noticed on that page?

Comment: That page explains the layout system at a high level. Are you looking for more information on how yield and passing blocks works, or are you interested specifically in the inner mechanics of how ActionView renders and combines multiple templates?

Comment: Yes, the rendering and combining part is the one I'm interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails renders inside out, so it will render the show.html.erb first and store that in a variable. It will then render the layout

inside the layout you see

```
<%= yield %>
```

which will get replaced with the shot.html.erb text

This is also how the following work. In your page, you might say:

```
<% content_for(:footer) do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And then layer in your layout you can:

```
<%= yield(:footer) %>
```

I like to think of it as just an inside-out setting of variables.

Comment: The part with rendering inside out is logical. So, at some point it boils down to a sub/gsub after yield, with the view's text?

Comment: right on, the <% xxx %> syntax executes, and the <%= xx %> syntax outputs.